# Laravel form validation in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables, Users, Companies, Attributes(with all kind of value)

A user has an account_id: `company abbreviation + account number` *(GOOGLE-01234)*

The abbreviation is from the company table and the account number is filled into the form.

So a company has a number where the next user account_id is started at which is put into the attributes table. So if a company has account_nr_start 1000 every new user will be 1000+ -> 1001 -> 1002 and counting up. But it is possible to set an own number as well for example 500, but this needs to be validated.

So it gets `abbreviation` from `company`, `account_nr_start` from `attributes` which makes `account_id` into `users`.

So I get all the account_ids with `$data = User::lists('account_id');` and then an if/else statement to check if the account_id is used.

For what I have now doesn't work!

Tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Controller:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request, User $user, Attribute $attribute)
{
$new_attribute = $attribute
    ->where('company_id', '=', Auth::user()->company->id)
    ->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start')
    ->first();

$new_attribute->fill($request->only('company_id', 'value'))->save();

$user->fill($request->only('email', 'firstname',
    'lastname', 'middlename', 'usertype_id', 'active',
    'company_id', 'title', 'btw_nr', 'kvk_nr', 'bic', 'iban',
    'birthday', 'mobile', 'telephone', 'country', 'city', 'postal_code',
    'house_nr', 'street'));

$user->account_id = $request['abbreviation'] . "-" . $request['value'];

$data = User::lists('account_id');

if ($user->account_id = $data) {
    return 'Used!';
}

else {
    return 'Usable!';

    // $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    //
    // $user->save();
    //
    // return redirect()->route('user.index');
}

$user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

$user->save();

return redirect()->route('user.index');
```

Blade:

```
@if(isset($user->account_id))
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('account_id', trans('common.account_id'), ['class' => 'form-label col-sm-3
        control-label text-capitalize']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {!! Form::text('disabledAbbreviation', $user->company->abbreviation, ['class' => 'form-control
            col-sm-3', 'id' => 'disabledInput', 'disabled']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('abbreviation', $user->company->abbreviation) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4  {{ $errors->has('account_nr') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::text('account_nr', null, ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-9', 'placeholder' =>
            trans('common.account_id') ]) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('account_nr', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>
    </div>

@else
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="{{ $errors->has('value') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            {!! HTML::decode (Form::label('account_id', trans('common.account_id').'<span class="asterisk"> *</span>',
            ['class' => 'form-label col-sm-3 control-label text-capitalize'])) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {!! Form::text('disabledAbbreviation', $abbreviation, ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-3', 'id'
            => 'disabledInput', 'disabled']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('abbreviation', $abbreviation) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4  {{ $errors->has('value') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {!! Form::text('value' , $account_nr[0]->value+1, ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-9',
            'placeholder' => trans('common.account_id') ]) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('value', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: The question title does not match the question at all, consider changing it.

Comment: You said account number is from a form, quote: " the account number is filled into the form", BUT then you said it's from the attributes table value + 1, quote: " the next user account_id is started at which is put into the attributes table"